# Loss function for comparing two vectors for categorization

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I am performing a NLP task where I analyze a document and classify it into one of six categories. However, I do this operation at three different time periods. So the final output is an array of three integers (sparse), where each integer is the category 0-5. So a label looks like this: `[1, 4, 5]`.

I am using BERT and am trying to decide what type of head I should attach to it, as well as what type of loss function I should use. Would it make sense to use BERT's output of size `1024` and run it through a `Dense` layer with 18 neurons, then reshape into something of size `(3,6)`?

Finally, I assume I would use Sparse Categorical Cross-Entropy as my loss function?

Comment: Why and how are you doing it at 3 different time periods?

Comment: @GaryOng I am using three different time periods because I'm trying to predict the results at 1 month, 6 months, and 1 year. I was trying to use the same ML network to do all three, rather than build separate networks for each time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bert final hidden state is (512,1024). You can either take the first token which is the CLS token or take the average pooling. Either way your final output is shape (1024,) now simply put 3 linear layers of shape (1024,6) as in `nn.Linear(1024,6)` and pass it into the loss function below. (you can make it more complex if you want to)

Simply add up the loss and call backward. Remember you can call loss.backward() on any scalar tensor.(pytorch)

```
def loss(time1output,time2output,time3output,time1label,time2label,time3label):
    loss1 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(time1output,time1label)
    loss2 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(time2output,time2label)
    loss3 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(time3output,time3label)

    return loss1 + loss2 + loss3
```

Answer (score 0):

In a typical setup you take a `CLS` output of BERT (a vector of length 768 in case of `bert-base` and 1024 in case of `bert-large`) and add a classification head (it may be a simple Dense layer with dropout). In this case the inputs are word tokens and the output of the classification head is a vector of logits for each class, and usually a regular Cross-Entropy loss function is used. Then you apply `softmax` to it and get probability-like scores for each class, or if you apply `argmax` you will get the winning class. So the result might be either vector of classification scores [1x6] or the dominant class index (an integer).

[image]
*Image taken from d2l.ai*

You can simply concatenate 3 such networks (for each time period) to get the desired result.

Obviously, I have described only one possible solution. But as it is usually provide good results I suggest you try it before moving over to more complex ones.

Finally, Sparse Categorical Cross-Entropy loss is used when output is sparse (say `[4]`) and regular Categorical Cross-Entropy loss is used when output is one-hot encoded (say `[0 0 0 0 1 0]`). Otherwise they are absolutely the same.

Comment: Since I'm trying to predict the results at 1 month, 6 months, and 1 year, your recommendation is to create three distinct neural networks? Or is it one NN with three outputs? If it is three outputs (e.g., `[3, 5, 2]` to signify class `3` and period `1`, class `5` at period `2` and class `2` at period `3`), what loss function do I use to compare it to, say, the correct result of `[3, 5, 1]`?

Comment: For example, comparing one time period sparse-categorical-cross-entropy is easy, say outputs of `[3]` and `[4]`, but if it's an array (`[3, 5, 2]` versus `[3, 5, 1]`) I am not sure exactly what to use as a loss function

Comment: I recommend you to create 3 different classification networks, each for specific time period  and then concatenate their outputs (a single integer from each one). In this case the networks will be completely independent and all it will be easier for you to train them. In this case your first network produces `3` as output and the correct answer is also `3`, same goes for second network, while the third predicts class `2` while actually it should be `1`.  In this case you will have to use Sparse Categorical Cross-Entropy loss. This is most trivial setup.